# Click event nested span

Tags: jquery

I´m trying to get the text with a click-event of some nested spans in an order closest to widest below my specific span 'annotation-container'. With my current code I get only the text of the clicked span. I need the text of every span below the span 'annotation-container'. After every text, I have to fire a function. Thank you for your hints.

Example 1 - click on 'test' (lowest level of nested span):

1st iteration text: *This is a test* (highest level of nested spans)

2nd text: *a test* (next lower level...)

3rd text: *test* (clicked span)

```js
$('body').on('click', 'span.annotation', function(e) {
  var text = $(e.target).closest('span').text();;
  console.log(text);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="annotation-container">
        <span class="annotation">
              <span class="annotation">This is
                   <span class="annotation">a
                       <span class="annotation">test</span>
                   </span>
              </span>
        </span>
        <span class="annotation">
              <span class="annotation">One more
                   <span class="annotation">great</span>
                        <span class="annotation">test
                            <span class="annotation">!</span>
                        </span>
                   </span>
              </span>
     </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `e.stopPropagation()` instead of `e.preventDefault()` to stop event bubbeling. And possible `this` instead of `e.target`.

And notice that you closed the `span` after `great` in your initial example:
`<span class="annotation">great</span>`

And why do you set your selector to `body` if you have a `.annotation-container`? It would be mutch nicer to use this.

```js
$('.annotation-container .annotation').on('click', function(e) {
  $($(this).parentsUntil('.annotation-container > .annotation').get().reverse()).each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });

  console.log($(this).text());
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="annotation-container">
  <span class="annotation">
    <span class="annotation">This is
      <span class="annotation">a
        <span class="annotation">test</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="annotation">
    <span class="annotation">One more
      <span class="annotation">great
        <span class="annotation">test
          <span class="annotation">!</span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: thx for your comments. But your example only gives me the clicked span. But I need all text of the spans hierarchically from bottom to top until the span 'annotation container'

Comment: Maybe update your question and make clearer what you want. I don't understand what you want then, and your question is poorly written. So please update it ... @mm1975

Comment: Ok. I´ve updated the description of the example 1. click on 'test' should give me 'this is a text' first, then 'a test', then 'test'